# Object Oriented Class Design - Mixin classes - Deciding on a effective class structure

Tags: c++, oop

I am designing a inventory type system for my company, and I have a few different types of products. A couple of them are combinations of 2 or more of the types:

**Base type**: Item

**Mixin Classes**: MA, MB, MC, MAB

**Derived Types**:

A (MA+Item),

B (MB+Item),

C (MC+Item)

**and packaged parts, which are**:

A+B (MAB + Item)

A+B+C (MAB + C)

*I will need to be able to add more to this hierarchy in the future.

I was considering using Mixin classes, where each individual part is derived from Item, and a Mixin class. I havent ever been real successful writting a hierarchy before. I really would to know if anyone thought that this was a good away to go about designing a system like this? If not, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance may result in less complex code.

It's up to you do decide which is simpler:

```
class MyItem : public MA<MB<C> > {}; // I'm not sure how your mixin syntax works.
```

or:

```
class MyItem: public A, public B, public C {}; // multiple inheritance
```